# .Net 5.0 Get User Email From Claims

Tags: c#, security, asp.net

From searching online I have identified two ways to get the user email, but I don't know if either has pro's/con's beyond Option.1 being a larger number of lines of code?

**Option.1**

I have a dedicated `ClaimsPrincipalExtension.cs` class, which I can call from anywhere in my app using `var email = ClaimsPrincipalExtensions.GetLoggedInUserEmail(User);`. Within which I have a method to get the email as shown:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Claims; 
    
namespace FunctionalLogicLibrary { 
    
public static class ClaimsPrincipalExtensions { 
public static string GetLoggedInUserEmail(this ClaimsPrincipal principal) {
if (principal == null)
throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(principal));
return principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email); }
 } 
}
```

**Option.2**
I just add using `System.Security.Claims;` to any class where I need it and use

```
var email = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
```

I'm just trying to learn here. Which method is more appropriate and why?

Comment: The first option hides the `System.Security.Claims` from the consumer-side, which is good. You can make that function as generic as the second one by parameterizing the `ClaimTypes`: `public static string GetClaim(this ClaimsPrincipal principal, ClaimsType claim) {...}`

Comment: Considering that its supposed to be an extension, why not `User.GetLoggedInUserEmail()` or even simpler `User.GetEmail()`?

Comment: In one of the apps I maintain there is a lot of code that involves Claims, and I've made sure to concentrate all that code into one class of extension methods. This way the code that uses these methods is simple to read, and anytime I need to add more Claims-related code there is a single page I just need to update (which also contains private methods that can be reused in some of the public methods).

Comment: I would suggest creating a class model for user, and bind user claims to the user class model. this would hide the cliams, and it will be easier to access and expand. so you can do `user.Email`, `user.Mobile`, `user.UserName` ...etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I frequently write extension methods for IPrincipal and ClaimsPrincipal objects (depending on .NET framework version). Creating an abstraction for a business concept is a good idea, because it centralizes this knowledge (think: Single Source of Truth). If this happens to change in the future, you have one file, one method to modify. Option 1 is preferred, since it simplifies maintenance.

Some additional improvements:

1. Call extension methods from the object context: `user.GetCurrentlyLoggedInUserEmail()`

   This is what extension methods are for. Take advantage of their syntactical sugar.
2. Do not duplicate concepts in the method name that already exist in the type it extends. This just makes method names too long for no added benefit: calling `user.GetEmail()` conveys the same information in a fraction of the characters.

   Plus, "LoggedIn" is contextual, and assumes you are calling this on a ClaimsPrincipal that is the currently logged in user. This is not something the .NET type system enforces, so your method name should not make this assumption.